# Quicksort with first vs last element as pivot

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

Here's the partition portion of quicksort with Hoare's scheme using the first element as pivot and last element as pivot:

```
private static int partitionUseLoAsPivot(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    int pivot = arr[left];

    while (left < right) {
        while (arr[right] > pivot) {
            right--;
        }
        while (arr[left] < pivot) {
            left++;
        }
        if (left < right) {
            swap(arr, left, right);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    return right;
}

private static int partitionUseHiAsPivot(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    int pivot = arr[right];

    while (left <= right) {
        while (arr[left] < pivot) {
            left++;
        }
        while (arr[right] > pivot) {
            right--;
        }
        if (left <= right) {
            swap(arr, left, right);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    return right;
}
```

They are almost identical except for the `left < right` and `left <= right` conditions.  Why?

Comment: They are almost identical except for the `left < right`, `left <= right`,  `int pivot = arr[left]` and  `int pivot = arr[right]`. You can debug this code running it step-by-step to see why this conditions are necessary.